# PHP Undefined Index Error ( New to PHP )

Tags: php, html, indexing, undefined

Notice: Undefined index: confirm in C:\xampp\htdocs\assurance\confirmation.php on line 98

```
$confirm = $_POST['confirm'];
```

---

```
<label> Retype Password </label>

            <input type="password" name="confirm" />
```

Comment: Read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index) to understand how to check if a variable or array key is set before using it, as in `if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) $confirm = $_POST['confirm'];`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running the form-handling code unconditionally, whether a form submission actually occurred or not.

You need something like:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
          ... a post occured, and the confirm field was submitted
   }
}

... show the form.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to assign the variable $confirm the value of $_POST['confirm'] when it hasn't been set. Add a check to the code to avoid the error.

Change:

```
$confirm = $_POST['confirm'];
```

To:

```
$confirm = ( isset($_POST['confirm'] ) ) ? $_POST['confirm'] : '';
```

Comment: Did you mean: `$confirm = isset($_POST['confirm']) ? $_POST['confirm'] : '';`

Comment: That would work exactly the same but adding brackets was something I did intentionally.

Comment: @NathanDawson you were missing the `?`

Answer (score 0):

did you submit the form?

by the way to espace the notice use

```
 if(isset($_POST["confirm"])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please check first:**

- Do you have a `<form>`-Tag before your `<input>`?
  `<form method="POST" action="path/to/file.php"><input name="confirm" type="password"> </form>`
- Do you have a button?
  *If you have something like a login form,  you need a button to "submit"*

  `<input type="submit">`

  ---

**Then write in your file:**

> if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
>   if(isset($_POST['confirm']){
>   /* Do whatever you want */
>   }
>   }